# Display Flex to align for Mobile or Responsive page

Tags: html, css

I want these below contents to have 50% width equally on PC's and 100% in mobile devices.

```html
    <style>
        .container {
          display: flex;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
    
        .box-left {
width: 100%
        }
    
        .box-right {
width: 100%
        }
    </style>
    
          <div class="container">
          <div class="box-left">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
            veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
            commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
            velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
            occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.
          </div>
          <img class="box-right" src="https://i.imgur.com/gawfygm.png" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Expand or Shrink the view to check if its working.**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box-left {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.box-right {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media(min-width:576px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .box-left {
    width: 50%;
    background: lightblue;
  }
  .box-right {
    width: 50%;
    background: lightcoral;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <img class="box-right" src="https://i.imgur.com/gawfygm.png" />
</div>
```